# Yii2 calling console controller from web controller behaving like web controller

Tags: php, yii2

What I am trying to do is like calling a console controller which should run in the background.

In the console controller action I have like:

```
public function actionCheckDomain($request_id){
....
 $wait = strtotime($model->start_time) - time();
           //  var_dump($wait);exit;
           ($wait > 0)?sleep($wait):'';
             
             $this->actionCheckDomain($request_id);
}
```

and web controller action I have

```
$controller = new RegisterController(Yii::$app->controller->id, Yii::$app);
$controller->actionCheckDomain($model->request_id);
```

Now what I see if my wait time is say 10 minutes, then browser times out.
What I want is that the console controller run in background.
but looks like calling console controller from web controller effectively it is behaving like web controller.

Note: Actually It is running in the background as I checked by closing the browser. The task was executed even after closing browser.
only issue now is like
browser continues to - like processing till wait time, how to overcome that.

Comment: You need a background [queue](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-queue) (or at least some simple cron job to pick these task and process them from console level). Calling console controller does not magically change context - if request is started from webserver level, it will be handled as web request and apache/php-fpm timeouts will take affect. You need to start new process from console to bypass these limits.

Comment: Hi Rob - I had a look at the queue you referred. it mentions that each task you send to queue should be separate class. so does that mean that if there are multiple users cannot use the same class for similar task? or same user cannot send another task to this class.

Comment: but here example suggests otherwise - Yii::$app->queue->push(new DownloadJob([parameter]) means we can send any number of tasks. am I right?

Comment: @Joshi You can push any number of tasks into the queue. To use queue in your case you should put the logic from `actionCheckDomain` into the job class (for example `CheckDomainJob`). You can have the `$request_id` as public property of that class and execute the logic from the `execute()` method. In your web controller you will create new instance and push it into the queue by `Yii::$app->queue->push(new CheckDomainJob(['request_id' => $model->request_id]));`. The job will be run in background and web request processing will continue without waiting for it.

Comment: @MichalHynčica - Thanks for the clarification- you stated that put the logic from `actionCheckDomain` into job class - what I have done is like copy the whole code of `actionCheckDomain` in execute method - is that correct? but I am getting error like - )The timeout specified has expired: [client ...] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling), referer. any idea about that.

Comment: That looks like something is taking too much time. Are you sure you are only creating the Job instance and pushing it to the queue in web action? You should not run the time consuming logic there. I would need more details about how you've implemented the Job class and your web action. Please update the question with more details or maybe start a new one focusing on this specific problem.

Comment: it looks like that was old error in log, that is already resolved. now what I see jobs are not run. do I need to use cron to execute the queue. like `./yii queue/run`

Comment: Basically yes. Pushing the jobs to queue only schedule them to be run by worker. It creates a record in DB or something similar based on what queue you are using. You have two options how to run the worker. First is as you've mentioned running the `./yii queue/run`, that command will run all scheduled jobs in queue and then end. The other option is to run `./yii queue/listen`. That launches a daemon that will keep running and execute the jobs as they will be coming into the queue.

Comment: I have created a separate question - which I thought it better. please take a look at - https://stackoverflow.com/q/65036998/1124993