# yii2 - yii2 queue - save to db and log not working within curl job

Tags: php, yii2

I am using https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-queue

I have function in execute method in queue class like:

```
$this->RegisterDomains($available,$registrar->end_point, $this->request_id,$model->user_id,$registrar->api_key);
```

and the registerDomains function looks like this:

```
public function RegisterDomains($available,$end_point,$request_id,$user_id,$api_key)
    {
        
        $model = CatchDomains::find()->where(['request_id'=>$request_id])->one();
        $PathToLog = 'runtime/domaincatch';
     
       if(!(is_array($available['domain']))){         
         $domain_list = $available["domain"];
         $url = $end_point."registerDomain?version=1&type=xml&key=$api_key&domain=$domain_list&years=1";
        
         $ch = curl_init();
             
             $LogFileHandle1 = fopen($PathToLog."/register.log", "a+");
             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
             curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true); 
             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $LogFileHandle1);
             $result = curl_exec($ch);
             $xml = simplexml_load_string($result, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
             $json = json_encode($xml);
             $response = json_decode($json,TRUE);
             $model->result=$result;
             $model->response = $json;
             $model->save();               
             curl_close($ch);
             echo $result;
        }
```

when I am executing yii queue/run from console.
The function is executing fine & no error is shown there. but nothing is saved in database for my `model->save()` or nothing is written in `register.log`
but if I am running the function without queue both this works fine.

Comment: You've forgotten to close your file stream with `fclose($LogFileHandle1);`. Also I would try to check the return value of `$model->save()` call. I can think of two possibilities why nothing is saved but no error is shown. 1) The `beforeSave()` callback returns false. 2) The validation fails.

Comment: I tried once again using `save(false)`. and running on cosole. I get an error that this domain is already registered and the same message is saved in db, but subsequent request with no such message is not getting saved.

Comment: You should also check the `runtime/logs/app.log`. The queue extensions uses some error  handling to prevent worker being terminated because of exception in one job. Thanks to that the exceptions are not displayed directly when running `yii queue/run` but they are logged.

Comment: I haven't use this queue before as such some behaviors looks quite strange. I have added - `var_dump("success");exit;` and run `./yii queue/run` but I am still not getting any output. what does this mean? though the domain request is going through.

Comment: Well, either the execution of your job is terminated by exception before it get to that point (exception is not displayed but should be in app.log). Or your condition `!(is_array($available['domain']))` is false and the code inside of `if` isn't executed.

Comment: I couldn't see any exception in `runtime/logs/app.log` as regarding `!(is_array($available['domain']))` - the function is executing this I can confirm because I am using sandbox api and the domain I am requesting is getting registered.

Comment: You will need to do some debugging to find what exactly is going on. You can either use xdebug to put a breakboint into your method and step through it or you can put some `echo` through your code to see where it will be executed and where it won't. The `echo` or `var_dump` should be in the standard output.

Comment: yes sure that is what I did, not `xdebug` but I tried to `var_dump` which is not sending any info to console or log file. please suggest a way for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225203/discussion-between-michal-hyncica-and-joshi).